# Following issues are visible in Manifest Analysis of the my app. How to resolve it?

Tags: android, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqGWt.jpg)

I am getting the following error during security audit of the app.

1.Broadcast Receiver (com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver) is not Protected.
An intent-filter exists.

2. Activity (com.google.firebase.auth.internal.GenericIdpActivity) is not Protected.
   [android:exported=true]
3. Activity (com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity) is not Protected.
   [android:exported=true]
4. Service (androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService) is Protected by a permission, but the protection level of the permission should be checked.
   Permission: android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE
   [android:exported=true]

Comment: I also found the broadcast receiver and service issues in my Flutter app using MOBSF. I presume your question is the same as mine: "How to get rid of those issues?". If I find something, I will post here.

Comment: I was able to reduce the severity of the issues from "high" to "info" in MOBSF related to the manifest for the lines which had a permission mentioned. This is the case for your line 4 with permission `android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE`. The following should be added to the root of your manifest: `<permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />`
You then need to test that your app continues to work as expected.

Comment: For the other lines, you will probably have to find where they are coming from and add permissions to them. The file `build/app/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/release/manifest-merger-blame-release-report.txt` may help.